# Typescript cannot find interface name but know the function defined

Tags: node.js, typescript

Why here `ReadStream` and `WriteStream` cannot been identified by typescript, while function `fs.createReadStream()` can be identified?
[image]
If compile, errors below throw:

```
app1.ts(3,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadStream'.
app1.ts(4,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WriteStream'.
```

All the interfaces and functions are defined in node.d.ts file.

Comment: Just an FYI, it's generally preferred for questions to have their code included as text rather than as an image.

Comment: :) I just want people to see the red wave lines. The code here is not so important. Thanks for your reminder anyway.

Comment: Curious as to why you are doing this. In my experience simply assigning the output of createReadStream will assign the stream to rs. Why the interface invocation?

Comment: Doing this so that can clearly see the type of the variable sometimes, and if a variable like `ws` is declared but not assigned yet, its type must be explicitly declared, right?  The syntax is right anyway, isn't? Maybe I have been affected by some other strong typed languages:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the definition file, I realized I should append the module name before the interface `ReadStream` or `WriteStream`:

```
import fs = require('fs');
let ws:fs.WriteStream
```

Answer (score 2):

You're variable declaration should be like:

```
let rs: fs.ReadStream = ...
```

This way you're telling TypeScript 'hey, these vars are `ReadStream`s which you can find the declaration in the `fs` module'.